# How to modify data from mongodb?

Tags: node.js

How to modify data from mongodb?

I have data from mongobd by query:

```
ProfileModel.find(
            {
                _id: {
                    $in: [
                        '63a0488c88723874c1fb3fbf',
                        '63a04894d4bdd0a191b69573',
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
```

Original Data From MongoDB:

```
[
 {
  name: "Name",
  image: "https//image......"
 },
 {
  name: "Name",
  image: "https//image......"
 }
]
```

I want to modify Original Data From MongoDB like this:

```
data: [
 {
   type: "User",
   attributes: {
     name: "Name",
     image: "https//image......"
   }
 },
 {
   type: "User",
   attributes: {
     name: "Name",
     image: "https//image......"
   }
 }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the data in your database? Or want to modify the output? Could you share a snipper from what you have tried already? I posted an answer but then I realized it may not be what you were looking for, so I have deleted my answer.

Comment: i just want modify the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an entire clean solution, but this will get you on the right way. You could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a new array using the original array you received from your database, see the following snippet:

```js
const someDataArray = [
 {
  name: "Name",
  image: "https//image......"
 },
 {
  name: "Name",
  image: "https//image......"
 }
];

const newArray = someDataArray.map(item => {
  return {
    type: "User",
    attributes: {
      name: item.name,
      image: item.image
    }
  };
});
console.log({ data: newArray });
```

Comment: thanks sir, it's work perfectly.. but, i think, i need implement with middleware to be clean like : [Mongoose Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74850943/7406010)